# Synology iSCSI Target - Install Ubuntu Server using PXE

Tags: iscsi, network-attached-storage, synology, pxe-boot

Massive iSCSI/PXE noob here.

I have a iSCSI target on my Synology NAS that I have attached in OSX using VirtualBox. I have the Ubuntu Server install ISO mounted on the Synology at `/volume1000/IsoMount/`

Can I install Ubuntu Server to the iSCSI target using PXE without routing traffic through the VirtualBox client machine? I'm currently remote on a shoddy internet connection and wanted to get the process started while I was away.

Is this even possible or an uneducated pipe-dream?

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You usually use PXE/TFTP to **boot** something. Like an installer.

Then of course if that installer (respectively the system you are installing) supports iSCSI, then you can install it to your Synology.

You however probably mix things up because you know that iSCSI as well as PXE "work using the network", however these are fundamentally different things.

Comment: I want to boot the Ubuntu Server installer using PXE to install to iSCSI drive.

Comment: Ok, PXE booting on the Synology, see here: http://www.synology.com/en-us/support/tutorials/583 Netinstalling Ubuntu, see here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/Netboot Not sure if the install ISO will help directly